# Macbook Pro freezes after trying to disable and reinable wifi after it has stopped working

Tags: networking, 20.04, broadcom, macbook, macbook-pro

After watching about 3 minutes of a YouTube video (or doing any bandwidth intensive task) my computer wifi stops, I then try to disable the wifi, so I can re-enable, but everything immediately freezes the second I click the "turn off wifi" button. I then have to hard shut off my computer to get back in.

I have not experienced this problem until recently and have tried everything I can think of to fix it. Reinstalling my wifi drivers, trying different browsers, trying to find any threads with the same issue, but it seems this is only happening to me (though people have had issues with the Broadcom drivers which might have something to do with this), completely reinstalling Ubuntu, and trying different wifi settings. And so far nothing has worked.

I have a MacBook Pro 13-Inch "Core i5" 2.5 Mid-2012 laptop.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 on a fresh new SSD in my mid-2012 a1278 model 13-inch Macbook Pro. The additional driver needed for my WiFi hardware is the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA from bcmwl-kernel-source. Wifi works fine the first few minutes the laptop is booted up, but it loses connection after a few minutes and when trying to turn off wifi the whole system freezes and can't be saved except for power interrupt. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue was fixed for me by following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/1198147

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)